# Prefill Microsoft Bookings web page form (it uses data-reactid elements) with URL link

Tags: reactjs, email, syntax, hyperlink, url-parameters

I'm trying to construct URL links, to include in emails, that pre-populates the recipient's information in the form on the site. The site is a Microsoft Bookings [site](https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/OsetionLLC@osetion.com/bookings/).

The placeholders are not the field IDs, but this is an example of what I'm trying to create:

https://outlook.office365.com/owa/calendar/OsetionLLC@osetion.com/bookings?Name=Kona&Email=konalion@msn.com

When I try to identify the individual form field IDs, for the URL parameters, I see that the form utilizes server-side data-reactid for all the elements.

**outerHTML**

```
<input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" data-reactid=".0.2.6.1.0.$0" data-keeper-lock-id="k-3jm7ib30q1p">
```

**selector**

```
#mainContainer > div > form > div.section.customerSection > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type="text"]:nth-child(1)
```

**Xpath**

```
//*[@id="mainContainer"]/div/form/div[6]/div/div[1]/input[1]
```

My challenge is understanding the proper syntax for the URL, if this is at all possible.  I've tried to reverse engineer the syntax in a variety of ways, but continue to get a Bad Request response, no change or an error redirect.

Any education provided is greatly appreciated.

Thank you